# Spark Dataset Parquet partition on s3 creating temporary folder

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

Spark`(version=2.2.0)` there is not `DirectParquetOutputCommitter`. As an alternative, I can use

```
dataset
    .option("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")//magic here
    .parquet("s3a://...")
```

to avoid creating `_temporary` folder on `S3`.

Everything works fine until I set a `partitionBy` to my Dataset

```
dataset
    .partitionBy("a", "b")
    .option("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")//magic stop working creating _temporary on S3
    .parquet("s3a://...")
```

Also tried adding but didn't work

```
spark.conf.set("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
```

With `partitionBy` at Spark Dataset, It's going to create `_temporary` and move files which becomes a very slow operation.

There is any alternative or missing configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hadoop 3.1's s3a will have a zero rename committer built in, (va HADOOP-13786). Until then, you can make use of its precursor, which [is from netflix](https://github.com/rdblue/s3committer/)

Note that "algorithm 2" isn't a magic step eliminating the _temp dir, just renaming task output direct to the destination when the individual tasks commit. Still prone to errors if there's a delayed consistency in the directory listing, and still O(data). You cannot safely use either the v1 or v2 committers directly with S3, not with the S3A connector as shipping in Hadoop 2.x

Comment: Yes, S3Committer!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives (in order of recommendation + ease - top is best):

1. Use Netflix's S3Committer: https://github.com/rdblue/s3committer/
2. Write to HDFS, then copy to S3 (e.g. via s3distcp)
3. Don't use the partitionBy, but instead iterate over all the partition permutations and write the results dynamically to each partitioned directory
4. Write a custom file committer

Comment: Uhmm I want to avoid calling Bash commands from my Scala code

Comment: Totally understand, then #1 using s3distcp is out. #2 is the best bet unless you want to get hacky by using spark to read and writes as blobs/bytes to s3. I haven't played with s3 commits partitioned using Algo 2 in a while, especially in a sterile (non proprietary cloud optimized) way.

Comment: You can reimplement basic distcp in spark itself, not much effort: https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/cloud-integration/blob/master/spark-cloud-integration/src/main/scala/com/hortonworks/spark/cloud/applications/CloudCp.scala